# Javascript PopUp when user quit the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

Good evening everyone !

On the following website [https://en.nomorigine.com/](https://stackoverflow.com), i'm trying to create a popup which appear only when the user quit the current page. I already implemented the code for the popup, but i don't know how to initiate it with Javascript when the user leave the page.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Here is my code, and i tried with the unload function from jQuery. But no success. Another method ?

```
<script>
(function(){
var expireKey = 'newsletter';      // Name of the localStorage timestamp.
var popupId   = '#get-newsletter'; // ID of the popup to display.

function maybeShowPopup() {

    // Check, if the popup was displayed already today.
    if ( window.localStorage ) {
        var nextPopup = localStorage.getItem( expireKey );

        if (nextPopup > new Date()) {
            return;
        }

        var expires = new Date();
        expires = expires.setHours(expires.getHours() + 24);
        localStorage.setItem( expireKey, expires );
    }
        
    DiviPopup.openPopup( popupId );
}

// Attach the scroll listener to the window.
jQuery(window).on('unload', maybeShowPopup );
})()
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `unload` event you've tried using is designed for cleaning up before a page is unloaded.  But, it's not reliable for user interaction because browsers generally restrict or prevent certain actions during this event type to avoid user experience issues.

Instead, the `beforeunload` event is what is typically used to detect when a user is about to leave a page. However, displaying a popup during this event is generally frowned upon and many browsers might be block it due to user experience concerns.

Nevertheless, if you still want to proceed, you can use the `beforeunload` event to at least attempt to show a popup when the user tries to leave the page. Here's a modified code example:

```
<script>
(function(){
    var expireKey = 'newsletter';      // Name of the localStorage timestamp.
    var popupId   = '#get-newsletter'; // ID of the popup to display.

    function maybeShowPopup() {
        // Check if the popup was displayed already today.
        if (window.localStorage) {
            var nextPopup = localStorage.getItem(expireKey);

            if (nextPopup > new Date()) {
                return;
            }

            var expires = new Date();
            expires = expires.setHours(expires.getHours() + 24);
            localStorage.setItem(expireKey, expires);
        }

        DiviPopup.openPopup(popupId);
    }

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
        
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = '';
        maybeShowPopup();
    });
})()
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, very appreciated ! But there is no way to display the popup without using beforeunload ?